# is_int returns double even if value is an integer

Tags: php, string, integer

Why does is_int() return double even if the value is an integer??

## example 1

```
$value = 1555555555;
echo gettype($value);
```

## example 1 returns

```
integer
```

## example 2

```
$value = 15555555552;
echo gettype($value);
```

## example 2 returns

```
double
```

Comment: Pretty sure it's because $value is > than 2^31 (highest 32-bit integer)

Comment: What is the value of `PHP_INT_MAX` on your system?

Comment: how can you then check if a value is NOT an float/double etc?

Comment: @clarkk: It *is* a double. There is a meaning in *limit*. Don't try to crash with your head into the wall.

Comment: how can you then check if the value has no decimals?

Comment: By using functions that treat those values as string and that offer calculations with higher precision: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.math.php - for example.

Comment: could you please give me a hint on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because You reached the limit of integer, read further here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php